# Django Forms; 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following:

**Models.Py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=40, blank=False)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Currencies, max_length=40, blank=False) 
    checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (['Name', 'Checkbox'])
```

**Views.py**

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return True
else:
    form = AuctionForm()


return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

This works fine, and shows me a nice form in test.html to fill in.
However, once I click the save button two things happen:

1) I get redirected to debug, where I see the following error.

```
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

2) My model gets updated and the information does show.

What am I doing wrong here?
Bool object has no attribute 'get'?
Is that my checkbox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't return `True` in your views method. Views method must either return `HttpResponse` or better, redirect to some other views using [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).